# UIScrollView - how is showsHorizontalScrollIndicator calculated?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

If `showsHorizontalScrollIndicator` is enabled, a small horizontal indicator is displayed at the bottom of the UIScrollView. I was wondering if anyone could tell me how this is calculated. The reason being, I want to display a custom indicator in a horizontal navigation system if there is content left/right, show/hiding when content is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following solution. Not the prettiest, but it seems to work. Requires `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender 
{   
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    [self scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:subNavigation];
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x <= 0) {
        [self scrollViewReachedLeftBound]; 
    } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.x >= 300) {
        [self scrollViewReachedRightBound]; 
    } else {
        [leftArrow setHidden:NO];
        [rightArrow setHidden:NO];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewReachedLeftBound
{
    [leftArrow setHidden:YES];
    [rightArrow setHidden:NO];
}

- (void)scrollViewReachedRightBound
{
    [leftArrow setHidden:NO];
    [rightArrow setHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just use `scrollView.contentOffset.x`.  If you want to know what page you are on, you divide by your page width (assuming you have a standard width).  So 
`int currentPage=(int)scrollView.contentOffset.x/SCREEN_WIDTH;` for example.  Now if you want to display a position indicator, like in the iOS homepage, you can do it in a loop in 
`-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender` something like

```
currentPage=(int)scrollView.contentOffset.x/SCREEN_WIDTH;
for(int i=0; i<pageCount; i++){
  if(i==currentPage)//display a filled in 'o'
  else //display an empty 'o'
}
```

Oh, BTW, `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender` is not called when the `UIScrollView` is initially loaded, so you perhaps should call it yourself (in order to display the indicator before the user has scrolled). You can also use `scrollView.contentOffset.y` off course, so you could easily adapt this to show a '+' shaped arrangement of 'o's, hinting at content above and below also.

Comment: In Oh Danny Boy's code, I don't understand why he is using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay--especially as his delay is 0. Surely better is just [self scrollViewReachedRightBound]; etc.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was playing with the delay value decrementing until I reached 0. I edited my post to reflect the change. Thanks for pointing this out and taking the time to answer.

Comment: Thank you "Oh Danny Boy".  I'm also thinking you could lose the 'scrollViewReachedLeftBound' and 'scrollViewReachedRightBound' methods and replace them with their 2 lines of code. I've just been working on my iOS like position indicator.